# Is this implementation of threaded long computation is correct?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I need to do a long computation (check the state on a remote server) of a list of items, and since the numbers of item can be large (from 1 to 100.000 at first), I thought it would be best to split and thread them.

Here's what I did :

```
// Retrieving list of items in the Database
Query<Platform> query = Ebean.createQuery(Platform.class, "WHERE disabled = false AND removed IS NULL");
query.order("created ASC");
Integer quantities = query.findRowCount();

int limit = (int) Math.ceil(quantities / 10.0);
PagingList<Platform> list = query.findPagingList(limit); // This will return a list of 10 pages, containing (quantities / 10) items

for (int i = 0; i < list.getPageSize(); i++) {
    CheckState task = new CheckState(list.getPage(i).getList());
    Thread worker = new Thread(task);

    // Start the thread, never call method run() direct
    worker.start();
}
```

And the CheckState class :

```
public class CheckState implements Runnable {
    private List<Platform> platforms;

    public CheckState(List<Platform> platforms) {
        this.platforms = platforms;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do the verification for each platforms
        for (Platform platform : platforms) {
            platform.executeLongComputation()
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is that it's preferable to limit the number of thread, so instead of splitting the result in pages of 100 items each, I prefer limiting the number of pages of n items inside. Doing so, I know I will always have a maximum of 10 Threads for each call to the original method (I can change it in the future to more or less in order to tweak the performances).

But I'm wondering if it's a good implementation, if this will work correctly. Say for example that the remote server won't answer, and I have a list of 1000 items inside, won't this cause problem (outside taking longer to complete) ?

Comment: Consider using an `ExecutorService` instead of managing the `Thread` instances yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I applied it using the Tutorial from Vogela. But despite having read it, I don't understand why it's better to use an ExecutorService. Do you have any good links ?

Comment: Sure, go through [this blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-7).

Comment: not very cool, because it's highly recommende to recycle threads, also having to much threads at a one time is not very good idea, because it slow down the process because of to much context switch, you may need [thread pool](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trpool)

Comment: @user2511414 what is not very cool ? my implementation or the "ExecutorService" suggested before ? (by the way, thanks for your reply)

Comment: your solution, you are attempting to run raw thread without any management of it. while executor service does.

Comment: Ok great, so ExecutorService will be the choice, Thanks all of you.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you can add your suggestion as an answer if you wan't, I'll upvote it and check it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to manage `Thread` instances yourself. Java already provides a way to execute asynchronous tasks in the form of [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). If you want to start a pool and re-use the `Thread`s as they become available again, use a `ExecutorService` with a `Thread` pool. You can get one with [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29). There are a number of other factory methods you might be interested in.

Keep in mind that a lot of threads means a lot of context switching. Test your environment for the best configuration.